# Is it useful to have separate access tokens and refresh tokens if they're going to be stored on the client-side as cookie?

Tags: authentication, cookies, session-management, rest, single-page-app

(This is a followup to my question about a general security scheme [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220204/is-this-security-scheme-using-passwords-short-lived-access-jwts-and-long-lived))

As part of an authentication scheme for a single-page application + REST API, I planned to provide authenticated clients with a short-lived access JWT and a long-lived, revocable refresh token. After some consideration, it seems like the best way to store these client-side would be as cookies with `HttpOnly` and `Secure` set, as well as `SameSite=Strict`. `HttpOnly` should protect against XSS attacks accessing the tokens, and `SameSite` should provide some protection against CSRF.

However, if both tokens are sent with every request, is there any benefit to having separate access and refresh tokens?  I suppose there's still the benefit of not requiring a database lookup while the access token is valid, but I thought part of the advantage of refresh tokens was that their exposure could be limited by only sending them on infrequent requests. Would it be better just to have a single, revocable token that requires a database lookup on every request?

Comment: Is the user with these access and refresh tokens a third party who is authorized to act on behalf of one of your service's users?

Comment: @Ghedipunk Nope, no third parties involved.

Comment: Then I don't see any reason to treat the refresh token as anything less than a slightly less secure password. Store it in a key-stretched form server side, store it securely client-side, and don't send it to your server unless you need it. And, since it isn't a password that the user themselves entered, don't trust that something on the client side computer can't read it (like a malicious browser plugin).